# Setting header values to empty in Karate

Tags: karate, automation-testing

In my testcase i am developing an API which is purposely having a missing header Value and i want to know that how can i pass an empty value in the headers in karate
for example: Header client-id :
this is a header with a missing value can anyone help me with this that how can we pass this in the request in Karate. just empty quotes
Header client-id = "" (like this)
OR
Header client-id = null (like this)
or any other method because if i am keeping it like this:
Header client-id - its giving me an error saying no step definition for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has to be something like this:

```
* header client-id = ''
```